# How to get the value of the selected row in Jtable

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I have this code

```
     ArrayList<User> list = bookList();
     dm=(DefaultTableModel) table2.getModel(); 
     Object[] row= new Object[3];
    for(int i=0;i<list.size(); i++){
    row[0]=list.get(i).getbooks();
    row[1]=list.get(i).getstrandSection();
    row[2]=list.get(i).getprice();
    dm.addRow(row);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Added to cart");
```

but the problem is when i click the button it add all the items to cart

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [ask] and then update your question, e.g. reformat it properly, add missing parts (e.g. there's at least one `}` missing), tell us why you're iterating over the entire book list etc.

Comment: Could you please add more details of what is your whole list and which is selected one in code, that will help to resolve it

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you.

Answer (score 1):

Where do you check which rows are selected?

> How to get the value of the selected row in Jtable

You use the `getSelectedRows()` method of the JTable to get the index of all the selected rows. Then you copy the data of each row.

```
   int[] selectedRows = table.getSelectedRows();
   Object[] row= new Object[3];

   for(int i = 0; i < selectedRows.length; i++)
    {
        row[0] = ...
        row[1] = ...
        row[2] = ...
        model2.addRow(row);
    }
```

Also, why do you have all the data in an ArrayList. If the data in in your JTable, then there is no need for the ArrayList to hold the data. Just get the data from the TableModel of your JTable. Don't keep data in two places, it is harder to keep the data in sync.